# detect ibeacon with android beacon library

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

Trying to detect an iBeacon setup on raspberry PI using the android beacon library (with xamarin bindings)

Wondering what Im doing wrong here:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 E2 0A 39 F4 73 F5 4B C4 A1 2F 17 D1 AD 07 A9 61 00 01 00 00 C8 00
```

And setting up Beacon Parser like so

```cs
beaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(new BeaconParser().SetBeaconLayout("m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

I can detect this beacon with for example "BeaconScope" on Android but I can not get it detected using the android beacon library.

I can see the following output from debug

```cs
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a1aff4c000215e20a39f473f54bc4a12f17d1ad07a96100010000c80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 06
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a1aff4c000215e20a39f473f54bc4a12f17d1ad07a96100010000c80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Setting up as AltBeacon works!

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1F 02 01 1A 1B FF 18 01 BE AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 C5 01
```

This one the library detects.

What am I missing?

I detect a RadButton setup as iBeacon but can not get it to work from raspberry PI

Comment: Just as an FYI: `hcitool` was [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) by the BlueZ project in 2017. The supported tools are `bluetoothctl` or `btmgmt`. Using `bluetoothctl` is a little more involved, but `btmgmt` still allows you do a beacon as a one-liner. For example `sudo btmgmt add-adv --adv-data 1BFF1801BEAC0000000000000000000000000000000000010001C501 --general-discov 1`. And `sudo btmgmt rm-adv 1` to remove the advertisement. You can do more with `bluetoothctl` and works without `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
"m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"
```

to this:

```
"m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"
```

Note the first digit is a 2 instead of a 0